# What would the layout XML look like for this?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is probably a very dumb question, but I had a few questions about what the layout XML looks like for these list items

[image]

I know there are three textviews, but how did they left indent the last line? Also, how did they cause the second textview to wrap after a set amount of lines?

If someone could post sample XML, that would be awesome too.

Comment: Its rather a custom listview. The last text is set to right using the gravity property. As for limiting the textview to x number of lines, use setMaxLines(x);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following xml, last textview is to the right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:maxLines="2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView 
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The last TextView is either layout aligned to the right (layout_gravity), or it matches the parent width and has its gravity (not the layout one, but its own) to right.

To ellipsize the second TextView, give it a valid height and then set the ellipsize attribute to end.

Answer (score 0):

The recipe is ScrollView + TextView + LinearLayout + gravity.
For the same look, check :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:textSize="24dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Morning"
    />
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display. A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through. "
    />
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Morning"
    android:gravity="right"
    />
        <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:textSize="24dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Morning"
    />
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display. A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through. "
    />
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Morning"
    android:gravity="right"
    />
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:textSize="24dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Morning"
    />
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display. A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through. "
    />
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Morning"
    android:gravity="right"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

(You can replace `TextView`s by a `ListView`)

EDIT : I guess everyone's giving you a bit of the solution here :).